# Ada: Serial port, String to Stream_element_array

Tags: serial-port, ada

```
        when 'B' |'b' =>
           cons.Put_Line("Enter text - less than 20 chars:   ");
           cons.Get_Line(Item => st,
                         Last => m);

           --buffer_ser'Write(st,m);

           ser.Write(Port   => S_Port,
                     Buffer => buffer_ser);
```

Defined as:

```
   package cons renames gnat.IO;
   package ser renames gnat.Serial_Communications;

   S_Port : gnat.Serial_Communications.Serial_Port;
   buffer_ser: ada.Streams.Stream_Element_Array(1..20);
   x : Ada.Streams.Stream_Element_Offset;
   m : Integer;
   st : string(1..20) := (others => ASCII.NUL);
   ComPort : GNAT.Serial_Communications.Port_Name(1..5);
```

Basically, I needed a very portable application, to operate an old device that overlays a video stream based on serial commands. I decided to try out Ada as I'd been learning it for something else.

How do I convert to a Stream_element_array(1..20) from a String(1..20) in Ada? I've tried the obvious answers, and I'm just totally stuck!

Edited as requested for the person who down voted me...

Comment: Please include the code **in your question** and not as an image. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Turn this snippet into an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've just read the MCVE guide. It's about as good as I can make it without breaking the minimal part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we need an MCVE.

```
with gnat.IO;
with ada.Streams;
with gnat.Serial_Communications;

procedure MCVE is

   package cons renames gnat.IO;
   package ser renames gnat.Serial_Communications;

   S_Port : gnat.Serial_Communications.Serial_Port;
   buffer_ser: ada.Streams.Stream_Element_Array(1..20);
   x : Ada.Streams.Stream_Element_Offset;
   m : Integer;
   st : string(1..20) := (others => ASCII.NUL);
   ComPort : GNAT.Serial_Communications.Port_Name(1..5);

begin
           cons.Put_Line("Enter text - less than 20 chars:   ");
           cons.Get_Line(Item => st,
                         Last => m);

           --buffer_ser'Write(st,m);

           ser.Write(Port   => S_Port,
                     Buffer => buffer_ser);

end MCVE;
```

it compiles successfully and fails with the error

> raised GNAT.SERIAL_COMMUNICATIONS.SERIAL_ERROR : write: port not
>   opened

A little reading on Streams shows that the answer to the actual question:

> How do I convert to a Stream_element_array(1..20)

is : normally, you don't. Streams take care of that for you.

A couple of modifications, respectively:

- make S_Port aliased so we can take its access (to allow redirectable stream Writes) and delete unnecessary intermediate variables
- actually open the serial port as a Stream
- write the string directly to the stream

look like

```
S_Port : aliased gnat.Serial_Communications.Serial_Port;
-- buffer_ser: ada.Streams.Stream_Element_Array(1..20);
-- x : Ada.Streams.Stream_Element_Offset;
...
gnat.Serial_Communications.Open(S_Port,ComPort);
String'Write(S_Port'access, st(1..m));
--buffer_ser'Write(st,m);
--ser.Write(Port   => S_Port, Buffer => buffer_ser);
```

But using fixed length strings when they aren't appropriate is a bad idea. Let's declare the string to be of the right length and simplify further. This requires a function form of Get_Line, which the Gnat.IO package doesn't provide, so let's use the more portable Ada.Text_IO instead. (And initialise the serial port name, and actually use the renamed packages...)

When we're done, we have something like

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with ada.Streams;
with gnat.Serial_Communications;

procedure MCVE is

   package cons renames Ada.Text_IO;
   package ser renames gnat.Serial_Communications;

   S_Port : aliased ser.Serial_Port;
   ComPort : ser.Port_Name := "COM1";

begin
           ser.Open(S_Port,ComPort);

           cons.Put_Line("Enter text :   ");
           declare
              st : String := cons.Get_Line;
           begin
              String'Write(S_Port'access, st);
           end;
end MCVE;
```

Comment: The MCVE documentation needs to be clearer ironically then.

Comment: This sits inside a loop - will the repeated re declaration cause issues? Do I need to manually free it, or will it self-clear at the end of the loop?

Comment: That's the beauty of the declare block : it "just works". Though the variables can be different size each time round the loop, they go out of scope at its `end` and are automatically freed (stack allocation is not mandated but its the usual implementation. So it's not like you lose efficiency for this simplicity). The less often you need tricks such as manual alloc/dealloc, or fixed length strings with separate "length" arguments, or other compromise solutions, the fewer bugs you'll have to find.

Comment: Not sure what's unclear about "Complete" in the MCVE documentation. Or "Verifiable". The doc asks you to test the code you're providing ... if it's not compilable, it's not testable.

Comment: Another nice feature of declare blocks is refactoring : they are good candidates for abstracting into procedures - perhaps local procedures, so local variables are visible without lengthy argument lists, if they aren't likely to be useful elsewhere.