# How do I get useful data from a UDP socket using GNAT.Sockets in Ada?

Tags: sockets, serialization, udp, ada, gnat

## Summary:

I am writing a server in Ada that should listen and reply to messages received over UDP. I am using the GNAT.Sockets library and have created a socket and bound it to a port. However, I am not sure how to listen for and receive messages on the socket. The Listen_Socket function is for TCP sockets and it seems that using Stream with UDP sockets is not recommended. I have seen the receive_socket and receive_vector procedures as alternatives, but I am not sure how to use them or how to convert the output to a usable format.

## More details:

I am writing a server that should reply to messages that it gets over UDP. A minimal example of what I have so far would look like this:

```
with GNAT.Sockets;use GNAT.Sockets;

procedure udp is
    sock: Socket_Type;
    family: Family_Type:=Family_Inet;
    port: Port_Type:=12345;
    addr: Sock_Addr_Type(family);
begin
    Create_Socket(sock,family,Socket_Datagram);
    addr.Addr:=Any_Inet_Addr;
    addr.Port:=port;
    Bind_Socket(sock,addr);
    -- Listen_Socket(sock); -- A TCP thing, not for UDP.
    -- now what?
end UDP;
```

For a TCP socket, I can `listen`, `accept`, then use the `Stream` function to get a nice way to read the data (as in `'Read` and `'Input`). While the Stream function still exists, I have found an archive of a ten year old comp.lang.ada [thread](https://narkive.com/VFhIjo8q) in which multiple people say not to use streams with UDP.

Looking in g-socket.ads, I do see alternatives: the `receive_socket` and `receive_vector` procedures. However, the output of the former is a `Stream_Element_Array` (with an `offset` indicating the length), and the latter has something similar, just with some kind of length associated with each `Stream_Element`.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/40045312/7105391, the way to change these types into a stream, is to not get them in the first place, and instead get a stream, which is not particularly helpful here.

Over at [this github gist I found](https://gist.github.com/nopid/653d3997c2d956ac621b) , `Unchecked_Conversion` is being used to turn the arrays into strings and vice versa, but given that the reference manual (13.13.1) says that `type Stream_Element is mod <implementation-defined>;`, I'm not entirely comfortable using that approach.

All in all, I'm pretty confused about how I'm supposed to do this. I'm even more confused about the lack of examples online, as this should be a pretty basic thing to do.

Comment: I ended up using an in-memory stream type I found at https://web.archive.org/web/20220326064410/http://www.pegasoft.ca/resources/boblap/11.html#11.12 (scroll down until you find the Memory_Stream package), but in the newsgroup I was told that Stream_Element being one byte is a safe assumption, so manually adding and multiplying these bytes is apparently the standard way of doing things if you don't have a stream.